# Can't get cookies with HTTP/HTTPS of Nodejs

Tags: node.js, cookies, node-https

I try with `https.request` but when I want access to cookie response, this don't appear on resource headers.
HTTP/HTTPS.

Example code:

```
let https = require('https');

https.request({
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    hostname: 'example.com',
    port: '443',
    path: '/example.html',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        "Pragma": "no-cache",
        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
        "Accept-Language": "es-ES,es;q=0.8",
    }
}, (res: any) => {
    console.log('headers', res.headers); // this does not show 'set-cookie' property.
})
```

have support to Cookies?
thanks

P.S: I'm using `typescript` to write and `ts-node` to run this script.

Comment: Please show us the code you are using so we can see exactly what you are doing.  Cookies are totally supporting with proper code.

Comment: Sorry, and thanks for you appreciation!

Comment: What's the value of `res.statusCode`?

Comment: the status code always is 200, and when I try with cURL, cURL does show me `set-cookie`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want the cookie-parser package from npm, and add

```
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
```

to the top of your app.js file, and

```
app.use(cookieParser());
```

to your middleware.  Cookies will then be available as req.cookies

Comment: I think the OP is making a request with `https.request()` and wanting to get cookies from that response which is different than what you're illustrating in your answer.